# Optimizar consulta compuesta de sub-consultas SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, sql

Tengo una tabla con mas de 100 mil registros y debo obtener solo 15 registros (No los últimos 15)

Este consulta tarda 00:01:45 (1 minuto con 45 segundos) en mostrarme la información.

```
select a.Silo, (select top 1 level from silos b where 
b.silo=a.silo order by b.insertdate desc ) as Nivel,
(select top 1 PERCENTAGE from silos c where c.silo=a.silo order 
by c.insertdate desc ) as Porcentaje,
(select top 1 InsertDate from silos d where d.SILO = a.SILO 
order by d.InsertDate desc) as Fecha
from silos a where substring(a.silo,1,4)='Silo' 
group by a.silo 
order by CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(silo,5,LEN(Silo)))
```

Esta en la información que me despliega

[image: resultado del query]

¿Hay manera de mejorar la consulta para que se ejecute mas rápido?

La tabla solo cuenta con esos campos.

Comment: ¿Las fechas se pueden repetir en un mismo `silo`? ¿Que versión de sql server usas?

Comment: mostra el explain plan, indices de cada tabla y cantidad de registros de cada una. por lo pronto, parece que esos subselects por cada registros son demasiado costosos e innecesarios...

Comment: y es mas, tu group by no hace nada de nada...

Comment: @gbianchi poque dices que no hace nada el group by? quiero pensar que no analizaste bien la pregunta.

Comment: @Manny, al no haber ninguna funcion de agregacion, el group by no hace nada que no haga un distinct. o sea, solo deja un registro por tipo. O sea, no hace nada que no se pueda hacer con algo mas rapido.

Comment: @gbianchi entiendo, tienes un ejemplo que pueda probar?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho las fechas no se pueden repetir para el msmo Silo. uso sql server 2008 standar edition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es la opción que suelo utilizar para obtener el primer valor de cada grupo. Le doy un número de fila a cada elemento particionando por grupo y luego sólo selecciono la fila número 1.

```
WITH cteSilos AS(
    SELECT a.Silo, 
        a.[level]      AS Nivel,
        a.[PERCENTAGE] AS Porcentaje,
        a.InsertDate   AS fecha,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER( PARTITION BY a.silo ORDER BY a.InsertDate DESC) AS rn
    FROM silos a 
    WHERE a.silo LIKE 'Silo%' 
)
SELECT Silo,
    Nivel,
    Porcentaje,
    Fecha
FROM cteSilos
WHERE rn = 1
ORDER BY CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(silo,5,LEN(Silo))) ;
```

Creo que sería importante que evalues el dividir tu columna `silo` para que no almacenes valores compuestos y todas las columnas tengan valores atómicos. Eso te ayudará a mejorar el rendimiento a largo plazo. Puedes mantener la columna `silo` como una columna computada.

Comment: despues de probrar mejoro bastante el desempeño a 14 seg, gracias por el aporte.

Answer (score 3):

No es necesario realizar sub-consultas para lograr el resultado. Puedes fácilmente lograr el mismo resultado primero obteniendo la fecha máxima del `InsertDate` de cada `Silo`, y luego haciendo un `join` con tu tabla de hechos.

Algo como:

```
with
qMax as (
select a.silo, max(a.InsertDate) MaxFecha
  from Silos a
 group by a.silo
)
select   a.Silo
       , a.level Nivel
       , a.percentage Porcentaje
       , a.InsertDate Fecha
  from silos a
       inner join qMax on qMax.Silo = a.Silo and qMax.MaxFecha = a.InsertDate
 where substring(a.silo, 1, 4) = 'Silo'
 order by cast(substring(a.silo, 5, len(a.silo)) as int);
```

Va a devolver el resultado razonablemente rápido siempre que exista un índice como este:

```
create index silosidx1 on silos(silo, insertdate);
```

Comment: La fecha no deberia salir de q? y el resto de los subselects donde quedaron?

Comment: Como digo en mi respuesta, las sub-consultas no son necesarias. La fecha puede salir indistintamente de cualquiera de los dos (al igual que ´Silo´), `silos` o `qMax` devolverán el mismo resultado, por lo cual es indistinto.

Comment: Genial, tuve que volver a leer tu respuesta para entenderlo (se ve que estaba nublado) :)

Answer (score 0):

Si solo son 15 registros y el top 1 para cada registro, es más fácil y rápido obtener las consultas individualmente. Por ejemplo:

```
create table prueba_max(
silo varchar(10) not null,
nivel int not null,
fecha date not null
)

insert into prueba_max values ('Silo1', 10, '08/01/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo1', 150, '08/20/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo1', 325, '08/06/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo1', 458, '08/02/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo1', 65, '08/09/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo1', 77, '08/15/2019')

insert into prueba_max values ('Silo2', 11, '08/03/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo2', 10, '08/30/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo2', 5, '08/07/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo2', 58, '08/02/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo2', 865, '08/09/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo2', 770, '08/10/2019')

insert into prueba_max values ('Silo3', 110, '08/11/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo3', 2150, '08/21/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo3', 3125, '08/16/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo3', 4558, '08/21/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo3', 566, '08/15/2019')
insert into prueba_max values ('Silo3', 7, '08/17/2019')


select s1.silo, s1.nivel, s1.fecha from (select top 1 * from prueba_max where silo = 'Silo1' order by fecha desc) s1
union all
select s2.silo, s2.nivel, s2.fecha from (select top 1 * from prueba_max where silo = 'Silo2' order by fecha desc) s2
union all
select s3.silo, s3.nivel, s3.fecha from (select top 1 * from prueba_max where silo = 'Silo3' order by fecha desc) s3
```

Con el siguiente resultado:

```
silo    nivel   fecha
Silo1   150     2019-08-20
Silo2   10      2019-08-30
Silo3   2150    2019-08-21
```

La consulta es rudimentaria y primitiva, si. Pero devuelve el resultado deseado y a un menor costo. ¿Puede mejorarse? Si, pero se necesita mejorar el diseño relacional de las tablas:

> Puntos de mejora

- **Agregar un indice** al campo Silo. Pero al usar una condición como`substring(a.silo,1,4)='Silo'` anulas el indice, porque debe aplicar la función substring a toda la tabla.
- **Normalizar la tabla**. El detalle de los silos debería estar en una tabla adicional. Por el hecho de no estar normalizada, es que la consulta original, aunque si puede hacerse, es demasiado costosa, porque recorre varias veces toda la tabla.

> Otra aproximación

Si la idea es traer 15 registros, uno por cada silo, siempre que no sean los últimos registros, puedes utilizar la función `max`:

```
select silo, max(nivel) nivel , max(fecha) fecha
from prueba_max
group by silo
order by silo asc
```

Con los siguientes resultados:

```
silo       nivel       fecha      
---------- ----------- ---------- 
Silo1      458         2019-08-20 
Silo2      865         2019-08-30 
Silo3      4558        2019-08-21 
(3 rows)Execution time: 0.037 seconds
```

De esta forma obtienes la fecha mas reciente y por consiguiente, los primeros registros.

[Este](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/df0507/1) es el fiddle en SQL SERVER.

Comment: El hecho de que uses UNION en vez de UNION ALL me hace cuestionar mucho la mejora propuesta.

Comment: @LuisCazares efectivamente, gracias, ya actualizo.